# How to add variables to an array

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have got a lot variables from A to Z.

```
$a = "bike"
$b = "car"
$c = "road"
...
$z = "street"

$array  = @()
97..122 | %{$array += "$"+[char]$_}
$array
```

When I type $array, it returns me :

```
$a
$b
$c
...
$z
```

But I want to get the values of these variables, not "$a", etc.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just want to have all these variables in one unique array.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using the single characters as variable names? Does it mean something in your context?

Comment: Well, in fact, it's just a "training" for me, it's just for personal purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what he really wants is to add the contents of those variables to his array, which can be done with `Get-Variable` as such:

```
$a = "bike"
$b = "car"
$c = "road"
$array  = @()
97..99 | %{$array += Get-Variable -name ([char]$_) -ValueOnly}
$array
```

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks! I know it's a bad way, but I am doing some comparaisons between "bad" and "good" practices with Measure-Command, etc. I would never do that in production obviously, it's just for personal purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Get-Variable`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849899.aspx) to access the variables:

```powershell
97..122 | %{$array += Get-Variable ([char]$_) -Value}
```

But may I suggest a different approach?  Instead of making dozens of simple variables, why not use a [hashtable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx)?  Something like:

```powershell
$table = @{ 
    "a" = "bike"
    "b" = "car"
    "c" = "road"
    ...
    "z" = "street"
}
```

You can then access the values through indexing:

```powershell
$table["a"]  # > "bike"
$table["c"]  # > "car"
```

Whenever have lots of simple variables that are of the form `$var1`, `$var2`, `$var3` or `$vara`, `$varb`, `$varc` you should stop and reconsider your design.  Usually, you can make your code far more elegant by simply using one of PowerShell's containers, such as an array or hashtable, to store the values initially.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes it works with hashtables, but I would like to keep my original structure, I want to generate variables from A to Z and then add to an array and read that.

Answer (score 0):

Try a hash:

```
$Hash = @{
    a = "bike"
    b = "car"
    c = "road"
...
    z = "street"
}
```

Outputting `$Hash` gives you:

```
Name                           Value    
----                           -----
c                              road    
z                              street    
b                              car    
a                              bike
```

Is that what you are looking for?